# How to run SelectCommand in <asp:SqlDataSource> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making QueryString parameter ,so I have two .aspx forms.  One form `Default.aspx` contains three fields SId, FirstName, LastName. when I submit the values, those values are saved in database.Now I want show this data on grid for particular SId on `default2.aspx`. Grid takes data through the SqlDataSource.SO I want to call the SqlDataSource on button click and grid should show data for particular SId on `default2.aspx`.

**Default.aspx** :

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>

  </div>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="SId"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="FirstName"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text="LastName"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tblastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnsubmit_Click1" Width="102px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />

</form>
</body>
```

**Default2.aspx** :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>
                SId</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>  
</div>

<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" 
    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
<Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SId">
          <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblSId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SId") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">
           <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'>

          </asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName">
           <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"  
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Student] where SId = @tbId">

<SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SId" QueryStringField="SId" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to call the SqlDataSource1 on button click like..

**Default2.aspx.cs** :

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {     
    string SId = tbId.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the button click. The `SqlDataSource` executes on every post back. The search button is going to issue a post back. But you are going to need to change a few things. First you need to get your parameters right, so remove this one:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SId" QueryStringField="SId" />
```

and put this one in its place:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbId" PropertyName="Text" Name="tbId" />
```

and now remove all of this code:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    string SId = tbId.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
}
```

and now the `SqlDataSource` is tied directly to the control value, so when the user puts in a new control value and clicks the button it will be applied and new data retrieved without any of your interaction.

Comment: @user2034832, fantastic, I'm glad I could be of assistance!